# Docusign REST API, search templates by name using REGEX / Pattern not working

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to search multiple templates by name using wild card such as "Star" "*"? 
So far following

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/

I have tried this

```
$baseUrl . "/templates?search_text=SpecialTPL_*"
```

And expect to get list of all templates starting with "SpecialTPL_", but it doesn't.

Comment: I have yet to try this, but I would expect the API to behave similar to what the web application does when you search for templates within your DS web account. I would actually retry this but remove the * since it's most likely trying to match the * character.

Comment: @LuisScott I had tried this all also, I tried various combinations and all fails, only worked if I put complete name of single template and then it return that template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` - A substitute for zero or more characters

`_` - A substitute for a single character